# F5 BigIP - HTTP Header Log Based on User-Agent Condition

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip

I'm a completely F5 newbie F5 trying to script an iRules to log the HTTP Headers if the User-Agent contains "Mozilla":

```
when HTTP_REQUEST_RELEASE {

    if { [HTTP::header "User-Agent"] contains "Mozilla" } {

        foreach x [HTTP::header names] {
            log local0. "$x: [HTTP::header $x]"
        }           

    }
}
```

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: What is not working as expected with your code ? What result do you expect ? IE11 returns `Mozilla/5.0` also (http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer). Maybe you are not seraching for the right string within user-agent ?

Comment: It's returning every HTTP request, I guess filtering is not working.